# What is the difference between "outlook", "viewpoint" and "perspective" in the scientific writing?

Tags: nouns, synonyms, comparison, writing

What is the difference between "outlook", "viewpoint" and "perspective" in the scientific writing, for the conclusion part (last section) of the article?

Should I use "outlook", "viewpoint" and "perspective" when I try to compare our works with other people's works?

Comment: I think it would depend on *how* you compare your work and theirs. You could also use some other words, such as *position*; for example, *"Our position on this matter ..."*.

Comment: In everyday English, these are usually interchangeable.  If there are specific distinctions in scientific writing, I am unaware of them.  Can you give an example of where you have heard them used in a way that seems they are different?

Answer (score 4):

All three words are nearly equivalent, although outlook to me implies an attitude toward future events rather than a current state of mind.

> From my **perspective**, the future looks grim, so I have a negative **outlook**. The **viewpoint** of my friend is quite different, so she is looking forward to next week.

I think the exact phrasing would depend on the type of comparison.

I find the [Wordnik relate](http://www.wordnik.com/words/perspective#relate) pages helpful when I'm looking for the right word. I particularly like the "Same Context" section because it has words that are related and not necessarily exact synonyms of the word I searched for. Some alternate words that might fit your meaning better are: insight, understanding, analysis, interpretation, conclusion, or treatment.

For example:

> Dr. Z's analysis of the problem was thorough, but our **insight** into the nature of the relationships among the factors leads us to draw a different conclusion. Our **interpretation** of the significance of outliers is quite different.